# Hibernate JPA Oracle12C- constraint violation exception on Primary Key(Sequence)

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, ojdbc

I am using SpringBoot application with Hibernate JPA.Oracle version - 12c , RAC setup with 3 nodes. I have four application Servers. 
For the below table :

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="order_payment_collection")
public class OrderPaymentCollection {

@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
Long id;
....
}
```

where I am using AUTO generation strategy, hence hibernate has created a sequence in DB :

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE  "test"."HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1798892 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

When concurrent inserts are happening from two different processes(running on different nodes), I am getting below error:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [*.SYS_C005080]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Which is PrimaryKey/Unique Index - Column ID for this table.

**Is it required while using Hibernate that we should use individual sequences for each node/process?**

I have a plan to resolve this :

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "seq", strategy = "com.test.utils.KeyGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
@Id
Long id;
```

In KeyGenerator class I am implementing IdentifierGenerator interface, getting nextVal from custom DB sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  test."PE_TABLES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 10000 MAXVALUE 10000000000000 INCREMENT BY 
1 START WITH 1798893 CACHE 1000 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

Hence Want expert opinion, **if I am missing anything or someone has faced this issue**. My solution to resolve the issue will be performant or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Within your entity, try changing the generation strategy to Identity / sequence. See below : `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ritika.I am using GenerationType.AUTO which will be resolved to GenerationType.SEQUENCE. So I effectively I am using GenerationType.SEQUENCE.